# Somar parcelas em aberto com Join

Tags: mysql, join

Tenho duas tabelas, `Cliente` e `Parcela`.
A tabela `Parcela` possui o `id do cliente` como chave estrangeira, uma coluna `pagamento` que é `null` ou contém a data de pagamento em formato `date` e uma coluna `valor` que é `float` e contém o valor pago ou `null` caso aberto.

Preciso somar todas as parcelas pagas e todas as parcelas abertas de todos os clientes.

Estou tentando fazer assim, mas está somando todas as parcelas e mostrando apenas o primeiro cliente.

```
select c.nome_cliente, 
SUM(CASE WHEN p.pagamento is not null THEN p.valor ELSE 0 END) as 'PAGO',
SUM(CASE WHEN p.pagamento is null THEN p.valor ELSE 0 END) as 'ABERTO'
from cliente c
LEFT JOIN parcela p
ON c.id = p.id_cliente
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso deve resolver, faltou você informar o `group by`

```
select c.nome_cliente
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN p.pagamento is not null THEN p.valor ELSE 0 END) as 'PAGO'
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN p.pagamento is null THEN p.valor ELSE 0 END)     as 'ABERTO'
  from      cliente c
  left join parcela p ON p.id_cliente = c.id 
 group by c.nome_cliente
```